# Accessing nested JSON collections in Google Firestore

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to accesses nested collections, as displayed in the image. I am able to access the fields using JS in the form `{{query.data['0'].name}}` but cannot access the collection 'customers'.

I have tried `{{query.data['0'].customers}}`, `{{query.data.customers}}` and a few other variants but I am unable and clueless as to how I can access the subcollection.

So far, I have seen people do it in other languages but I am unsure how to access it here - [this is my db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jo0U5.png)

Comment: please attach a full image of your db to see what is on the right and left of it

Answer (score 2):

A query for a top-level collection will not return documents from nested subcollections.  If you want data from a subcollection, you have to query it specifically using the names of the collections and documents to build a path to that subcollection.

```
firestore
    .collection("topLevelCollection")
    .doc("documentId")
    .collection("nestedCollection")
    .get()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I cannot use this format. In my answer I wrote JS but I think I meant to write JSON. I am not sure if it is JSON though, however I am not sure how I can access collections using the language of the query

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean.  JSON is not a query language in JavaScript.  The provided JavaScript SDK provides an API for querying with I've shown here.